# ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER hangs

Tags: ssh, ansible, yaml, virtual-machine

I'm trying to synchronize a remote VM with a playbook but it hangs in the ssh connection; I will be grateful for your help; this is the detail of the error :

```
   root@pve:~# ansible-playbook   ansible/playbook/timezone.yml  -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.7.7
 config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
 configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
 ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
 executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
 python version = 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) [GCC 8.3.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
/etc/ansible/hosts did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
/etc/ansible/hosts did not meet script requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: timezone.yml *************************************************************************************************1 plays in ansible/playbook/timezone.yml

PLAY [Set timezone and configure timesyncd] ****************************************************************************META: ran handlers

TASK [set timezone] ****************************************************************************************************task path: /root/ansible/playbook/timezone.yml:6
<10.10.2.56> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ibrahimy
<10.10.2.56> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ibrahimy -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/b542c5a8f2 10.10.2.56 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ibrahimy && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.10.2.56> (0, b'/home/ibrahimy\n', b'')
<10.10.2.56> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ibrahimy
<10.10.2.56> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ibrahimy -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/b542c5a8f2 10.10.2.56 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/ibrahimy/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir /home/ibrahimy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640189176.0268686-25363-16402981562839 && echo ansible-tmp-1640189176.0268686-25363-16402981562839="` echo /home/ibrahimy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640189176.0268686-25363-16402981562839 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.10.2.56> (0, b'ansible-tmp-1640189176.0268686-25363-16402981562839=/home/ibrahimy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640189176.0268686-25363-16402981562839\n', b'')
Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
<10.10.2.56> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-25357npsegr7h/tmpzsxo66mr TO /home/ibrahimy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640189176.0268686-25363-16402981562839/AnsiballZ_command.py
<10.10.2.56> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ibrahimy -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/b542c5a8f2 '[10.10.2.56]'
<10.10.2.56> (0, b'sftp> put /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-25357npsegr7h/tmpzsxo66mr /home/ibrahimy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640189176.0268686-25363-16402981562839/AnsiballZ_command.py\n', b'')
<10.10.2.56> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ibrahimy
<10.10.2.56> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ibrahimy -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/b542c5a8f2 10.10.2.56 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/ibrahimy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640189176.0268686-25363-16402981562839/ /home/ibrahimy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640189176.0268686-25363-16402981562839/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.10.2.56> (0, b'', b'')
<10.10.2.56> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ibrahimy
<10.10.2.56> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ibrahimy -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/b542c5a8f2 -tt 10.10.2.56 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 /home/ibrahimy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640189176.0268686-25363-16402981562839/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
```

while collecting information it connects successfully, but while performing task it crashes and the error is as follows:

```
fatal: [10.10.2.56]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "timedatectl set-timezone Africa/Casablanca",
    "delta": "0:00:25.834940",
    "end": "2021-12-22 02:44:26.708523",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "timedatectl set-timezone Africa/Casablanca",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2021-12-22 02:44:00.873583",
    "stderr": "\u001b[0;1;31mFailed to set time zone: Connection timed out\u001b[0m",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "\u001b[0;1;31mFailed to set time zone: Connection timed out\u001b[0m"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

the playbook file :

```
- name: Set timezone and configure timesyncd
  hosts: "*"
  gather_facts: yes
  become: no
  tasks:
  - name: set timezone

    shell:  timedatectl set-timezone Africa/Casablanca
```

Comment: The ssh connection is absolutely fine. In fact you performed 3 ssh connection successfully before the fourth where the actuall command hangs on the remote host. Please edit your question and add your playbook with the `command` task that is hanging.

Comment: @Zeitounator  Thanks for your reply, I made the change in the post

Comment: 1) What happens when you run that command yourself as the "normal" user you are connecting with on the target (since you don't escalate privileges)? Does it wait for a user input? (please edit your post with the information) 2) using shell to perform actions for which there is a [dedicated module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/timezone_module.html) is a bad practice.

Comment: Per previous responce, I would use sudo for timedatectl